# Java replaceAll with Backslashes

Tags: java, escaping

For this simple program ...

```
import java.lang.String;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        String s = "Hello <BSLASH>";
        String sReplaced = s.replaceAll("<BSLASH>", "\\\\");

        System.out.println("s = " + s);
        System.out.println("sReplaced = " + sReplaced);

    }
}
```

Why doesn't sReplaced equal Hello \\ with 2 backslashes?

```
$javac test.java
$ java test
s = Hello <BSLASH>
sReplaced = Hello \
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll` for this, use `replace`:

```
String sReplaced = s.replace("<BSLASH>", "\\\\");
```

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression, which is not necessary here (this is why `\\\\` evaluates to `\`).

Oh, and you really don't need `import java.lang.String` - the `String` class is imported by default.

Comment: This actually worked for me. thanks. Thanks for explaining the regex part too.

Comment: It's not just `String` imported by default, it's the whole `java.lang` package, as if every program has `import java.lang.*;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Since replaceAll uses regex, it actually does escape four slashes to two then the escape for backslash is another backslash.

So your code is actually just \

To Replace it with two backslash, it should be

```
String sReplaced = s.replaceAll("<BSLASH>", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Comment: @Kevin the above works perfectly on windows. may be you are using linix.

Comment: Yea, Ubuntu. Why would it matter? Isn't Java cross-platform?

Comment: it does not matter btw. Anyways, I am pretty sure this works since I tested this in multiple OS. I have mac, centos, ubuntu and windows vista and they all output the same. Glad ARS can resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

you should use total of 8 backslash's to get 2 backslashes. single backslash should be escaped with one backslash,backslash is a meta character is regex world, in-order to consider it as a normal character you will have to escape it againwith two backslash's.

```
 String sReplaced = s.replaceAll("<BSLASH>", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Comment: @Kevin the above works perfectly on windows. may be you are using linix.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR That shouldn't make a difference, but what you have should work and result in `Hello \\ `.

Comment: @A.R.S. but, i tested it and got **Hello \\** as output, what's your say ?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR, it does or does not work for you?

Comment: @Kevin as said earlier,it works perfectly forme with output `Hello \\\`

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR sorry. I did get Hello \\\\, but mistakenly forgot that \\\\ means 2 backslashes. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

I also suggest to use `replace` instead `replaceAll` .
I write here a code to fix the issue, and to try to explain how use Backslash in java string.

```
String bs1="\\";
String bs2="\\";
String sReplaced = s.replace("<BSLASH>", bs1.concat(bs2));
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I believe adding 2 variables and concatenation introduces unnecessary complexity.